# convert linklist to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I am trying to create a method to convert a linked list into arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> toList(){
    //Node node;
    Node current = node;
    while(current != null){
        current = current.next;
        array.add(current.val);
    }
}
```

and it shows error below

```
no suitable method found for add(Object)
method ArrayList.add(int,Integer) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method ArrayList.add(Integer) is not applicable
  (actual argument Object cannot be converted to Integer by method invocation conversion)
```

I am currently using JDK 1.7 which from what I found in this forum, JDK 1.7 should be good with this matter. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current.val` is typed as `Object` whereas the add method expects an `Integer`. Either you need a cast, or you need to type the `Node` using generics to ensure that `node.val` is an Integer.

Answer (score 4):

`node.val` is of type `Object`, while add expects an `Integer`. Either change the `node.val` type to `Integer` (or make it generic), cast the value to an `Integer` or change `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<Object>`

Answer (score 1):

I assume "node" refers to the head of the linkedlist. Not directly related with your problem but your iteration is wrong. You are iterating current first, then you are taking the value of it. So you lost the value of first element. You should add first, then iterate to next.